Algorithm to open a delta neutral position
I'm not sure how to articulate this problem exactly but what I am looking for as an answer is what approaches could be used to open a delta neutral position for the similar assets across exchanges that will minimise overall loss, where the price on the one exchange doesnt keep a perfect price parity on another exchange. I am trying to create a long position for an asset on one exchange and a short position on another, while the prices do keep a relative close parity it sometimes diverges or converges I want to slowly increase the overall position size on both exchanges but also while doing so counter act the convergance or divergance so that I can keep a good delta neutral overall ie so that the loss on either is balanced by the gain on the other.

This is quite subjective and opinion based. I will leave it open but I suspect it might get voted closed by forum members. Perhaps someone might share a link to published research on the subject.

I am hoping for a reseach paper or investigation that someone else has done how could a rephase this differently so as not leave it subjective
